# Problema Inner join e Left join

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

Estou usando o banco de dados PostgresQL + C#

Tenho um Type que podemos chamar de Principal. Dentro dele tenho um long id, string nome, tenho uma ClasseA, ClasseB, ClasseC. Tanto a ClasseA, ClasseB, ClasseC pode ou não ser preenchido então para efetuar a consulta utilizo o LEFT JOIN e faço a consulta sem problema.

Agora dentro da ClasseA eu tenho a ClasseZZ, é uma classe que eu preciso buscar obrigatoriamente junto com a ClasseA, então para fazer isso eu utilizo INNER JOIN, assim eu trago as informações da ClasseZZ para ser preenchida dentro da ClasseA

Agora o problema: como nessa consulta as dados da ClasseA pode retornar null, e quando isso ocorre, não está retornando uma única linha, já que eu tenho um inner join entre a ClasseA e a ClasseZZ. Se eu modifico esse Inner join entre a ClasseA e a ClasseZZ eu recebo os dados sem problemas.

ai fica a pergunta: é possível fazer essa consulta em uma unica consulta SQL? ou terei que dividir em duas?

EDIT: ou ter que fazer um "gambiarra" e deixar todas as junções de tabelas como LEFT JOIN?

EDIT2: Segue codigo SQL:

SELECT at_atendimento.Atendimento AS at_atendimento_Atendimento, 
at_atendimento.Data AS at_atendimento_Data, 
at_atendimento.fechado AS at_atendimento_fechado,
at_atendimento.transmitido AS at_atendimento_transmitido, 
at_atendimento.Id AS at_atendimento_Id, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Documento AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Documento,
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Documento2 AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Documento2, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.RazaoSocial AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_RazaoSocial,
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.NomeFantasia AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_NomeFantasia,
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Cep AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Cep, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Endereco AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Endereco,
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Numero AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Numero,
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Complemento AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Complemento,
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Bairro AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Bairro, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Cidade AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Cidade, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Estado AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Estado, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.RamoPrincipal AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_RamoPrincipal, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Tel1 AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Tel1, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Ramal1 AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Ramal1, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Tel2 AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Tel2, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Ramal2 AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Ramal2,
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.IsEmiteBoleto AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_IsEmiteBoleto, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.TipoDocumento AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_TipoDocumento, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.AutorizacaoLancamento AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_AutorizacaoLancamento,
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Id AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente_Id, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao.Cartao AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_Cartao, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao.CodigoAdministrativo AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_CodigoAdministrativo, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao.Contrato AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_Contrato, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao.Validade AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_Validade,
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao.SigepUser AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_SigepUser, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao.SigepSenha AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_SigepSenha, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao.Descricao AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_Descricao, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao.desativado AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_desativado, 
at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao.Id AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_Id 
FROM at_atendimento AS at_atendimento 
LEFT JOIN cad_cliente_cartao AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao ON at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao.Id = at_atendimento.cad_cliente_cartao_id 
JOIN cad_cliente AS at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente ON at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao_cad_cliente.Id = at_atendimento_cad_cliente_cartao.cad_cliente_id

Comment: Você tem que saber como estão organizadas as tabelas de seu banco dados e daí utilizar o tipo de junção específico para o que deseja obter como resultado da consulta.

Comment: Ao invés de tentar descrever, apresente o seu código e estrutura de verdade para que a pergunta faça sentido e você tenha um [mcve]

Comment: segue codigo SQL, peço desculpas pela demora, os dados estava na empresa

Comment: "Agora dentro da ClasseA eu tenho a ClasseZZ, é uma classe que eu preciso buscar obrigatoriamente junto com a ClasseA, então para fazer isso eu utilizo INNER JOIN, assim eu trago as informações da ClasseZZ para ser preenchida dentro da ClasseA

Agora o problema: como nessa consulta as dados da ClasseA pode retornar null, e quando isso ocorre, não está retornando uma única linha, já que eu tenho um inner join entre a ClasseA e a ClasseZZ. Se eu modifico esse Inner join entre a ClasseA e a ClasseZZ eu recebo os dados sem problemas." a que tipo de modificação da junção você se refere?

Comment: não é modificação, é um select, preciso trazer as informações e se eu usar um inner join na classe left join, se essa classe que é left join for null, ele não retorna nada

Comment: "Se eu modifico esse Inner join entre a ClasseA e a ClasseZZ"?

Comment: Você está tentando dar um join na mesma tabela??? o.0

Answer (score 0):

Eu ja lidei com um problema bem parecido. Segue essa imagem aqui. Acredito que uma das 3 da direita seja exatamente o que vc ta querendo. Na cláusula where vc põe a condição null (no caso DBNull)[image: Olhe essa imagem]

Comment: essa parte eu até sei, agora e se ter uma coluna C logo após o B que é INNER JOIN sendo que B é LEFT JOIN se B for null nenhuma linha é carregada que é esse meu problema